# Как узнать, ведет ли url ссылка на страницу сайта или на загрузку файла?

Tags: python, парсер

Столкнулся с проблемой. Разрабатываю мобильный клиент для просмотра групп ВКонтакте. В аттачах к постам показываю ссылки. Мне нужно открыть такую ссылку в стандартном браузере девайса, если ссылка ведет на страницу в сети или начать загрузку средствами моего приложения, если ссылка указывает на файл. Я не думал, что это может стать настоящей проблемой, поскольку, например модуль `urlparse` оказался абсолютно бесполезным:

```
print(urlparse('http://play.google.com/store/details?id=org.name.old&rdid=org.name.old).path)
>>> play.google.com/store/details
```

И такая ссылка:

```
print(urlparse('http://page/file.txt).path)
>>> /file.txt
```

И тут становится совершенно непонятно, как определить, на что указывает ссылка `http://play.google.com/store/details?id=org.name.old&rdid=org.name.old`. Очевидно, что, например, модуль `os` здесь тоже мало чем поможет.

Неужели нужно применять `os.path.splitext`, выдергивая из ссылки расширение, если оно есть, и проверять, принадлежит ли это расширение к известным типам файлов?

Comment: Узнать, на что указывает ссылка, без перехода по ней невозможно в принципе ни для каких ссылок

Comment: А метод HEAD вам не поможет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно получать только заголовок `http` ответа, и в нем смотреть `content-type`. Если это он содержит `text/html`, значит это web-страница.

Пример:

```
import requests

url = 'https://yandex.ru'
r = requests.head(url)
print(r.headers['content-type'])  # 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'

# Ссылка на скачивание заглавной страницы Википедии в виде pdf
url = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/pdf/Заглавная_страница'
r = requests.head(url)
print(r.headers['content-type'])  # 'application/pdf'
```

Для обработки редиректов при запросе нужно указывать `allow_redirects=True` (по-умолчанию для функции `head` [отключено](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L88)):

```
url = 'http://ya.ru'  # Редиректит на https://ya.ru
r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
print(r.headers['content-type'])  # 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
```

Comment: Да, пожалуй, это действительно единственный правильный способ. Извините, пока не могу принять ваш ответ в силу того, что нахожусь здесь с мобильного устройства, и страница не имеет ссылки "Принять ответ". Доберусь до компьютера, обязательно приму.

Comment: показывается ли pdf или другой тип прямо в браузере или закачивается как файл, определяется  [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) заголовком.

Answer (score 1):

Если [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) http заголовок говорит, что attachment, то скачивайте ссылку как файл (имя в заголовке может быть указано). Одно и то же содержимое может показываться inline или cкачиваться в зависимости от этого заголовка, [rfc 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266):

> If the disposition type matches "attachment" (case-insensitively),
> this indicates that the recipient should prompt the user to save the
> response locally, rather than process it normally (as per its media
> type).

На Питоне:

```
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as r:
    if r.headers.get_content_disposition() == 'attachment':
        download(r)
    else:
        process_as_usual(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо определить, оканчивается ли ссылка каким-то конкретным расширением, указанным в коде.

***Если оканчивается***, скачивает.

***В противном случае*** - открывает в стандартном браузере страницу.

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit  
import webbrowser
import wget

url = 'http://play.google.com/store/details?id=org.name.old&rdid=org.name.old' # Или же http://page.com/file.txt
if not urlsplit(url)[2].endswith(".txt") and not urlsplit(url)[2].endswith(".mp4"): # И так далее.
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
else:
    wget.download(url, out="dl_content/file.txt")
```

Comment: Это попадает под `Неужели нужно применять os.path.splitext, выдергивая из ссылки расширение, если оно есть, и проверять, принадлежит ли это расширение к известным типам файлов?`

Comment: @Alban да, Вы правы. Что ж, я попытался =)